# Restrict Internet access to only a web browser in active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

I have a Small Office Network Connected to a Server running windows server 2016.
The Server functions as DNS, DHCP Server, Domain Controller and Gateway( Two NICS, One lan connection & one WAN connection) 
I want to restrict Internet Access of Client Computers joined to the domain to a specific app(Google Chrome), Windows Update using WSUS.

I want the LAN access to work freely.

Would love some suggestion on how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7):

Сonfigure the GPO or change registry keys to allow the internet connections only for specific application. You can check the detailed info using guidances below:

https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/configuring-internet-restrictions-with-internet-communications-management-with-group-policy/

https://www.gypthecat.com/how-to-block-internet-access-with-group-policy

Comment: Hi, please note I think the first guide is a on or off settings for internet, not sure as I dont know specificly that setting, but might be hard to exclude an app from that setting